# Rails override scope option

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Much more like overriding order

```
Entity.associations.order("field ASC").reorder("other_field DESC") 
# => result: GET ... order by other_filed DESC
```

Is it possible to override scope options?

```
Entity.associations.where("field = 1").where("field = 2")
# => GET ... where "field" = 1 and "field" = 2

# Desirable:
Entity.associations.where("field = 1").rescope(where("field = 2"))
# => GET ... where "field" = 2
```

P.S.
Rails 3

P.S.S
Accepted answer is valid for Rails4

Comment: Have you tried the [unscope](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#unscope) method?
I was wondering if it works for example in your case with two where's.

Comment: @AndréHerculano, that would be the answer unless: `Entity.where(parent_id: 1).class => ActiveRecord::Relation` , `Entity.where(parent_id: 1).respond_to?(:unscope) => false`. Could not find the `unscope` method in Rails API also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [unscope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-unscope) method to remove your where conditions completely:

```
Entity.asscocations.where(field: 1).unscope(:where).where(field: 2)
```

Or just remove a specific field from your where conditions:

```
Entity.asscocations.where(field: 1).unscope(where: :field).where(field: 2)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work in 3.2.6. `ActiveRecord::Relation.instance_methods.include? :unscope # => false`. I should have specified the version

Comment: Seems like there's none in Rails3, tnx